# To create split list without using anchor tag

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have created a split listview using jquery mobile.

Eg. Using this format i.e. using two anchor tags.

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-split-icon="delete" data-split-theme="d"               data-inset="true">
    <li>
             <a href="#">
                <img src="http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.0/docs/_assets/img/album-                                                                              bb.jpg">
                <h2>Broken Bells</h2>
                <p>Broken Bells</p></a>
                <a class="foo">Purchase album</a>
            </li>
</ul>
```

This displays intented content properly. But as the list size grows, I have observed that list scrolling becomes terribly slow. If I remove those anchor tags then I can scroll the list smoothly. But If I remove those anchor tags, it looses the flavor of split list. Is there any way to still show the split listview without using anchor tags?
Thanks.